# iOS: How to define an app as popular app near me on Appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

i'm trying to make and app that can be used inside museums and i was wondering ..
 how to make the Appstore recommend the app for users near museums ?

i've tried to make a routing geojson file but the validator tells me that i should make the app binary as routing app .. 
and i'm not sure that what i want .
 i'm using xcode 4.5 and targeting ios 5 to 7

[image]

what should i do cause i've tried to google for it but it seems that i'm not using the proper keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing the "Apps Popular Near You" feature on the app store with routing apps.

You can't opt into "Popular Near Me" - apps are displayed there automatically based upon analytical data that Apple collect. If you would like your app to be displayed in the list when users are near museums you'll just have to hope your users actually use the app when they're near museums!

The routing geojson you are trying to get to work is for apps to interface with Maps, not the "popular near me" section on the app store.